# Openshift not running PHP/MySQL portions of code

Tags: openshift, openshift-cartridge, openshift-php-cartidges

I am using the Openshift by Redhat service to host my web site. Free plan. The site uses HTML, PHP, SQL, Javascript, AJAX, and JSON.

When I run the code using my local server, it works as expected. When I run it through Openshift the PHP/SQL portions don't work. Which is why I think it's a server problem, not a code problem, so I won't post any of the code for now.

Here's a couple shots to clarify:

- [Openshift cartridges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKETa.png) Notice the PHP cartridge status is "idle"
  while SQL is "started" ???
- [phpMyAdmin not allowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qtyH.png) Thought I had to add phpMyAdmin but I
  can't. Why?

Answer (score 0):

There are some troubleshoot mechanisms that you can possibly use to define why the PHP cartridge is idle. Since the PHP cart is idle it could not start for some reason, there may be Openshift specific environment variables https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html that need to be setup or dependencies that you have on your local machine, but the cartridge does not know about. You can follow this link https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-log-files.html to see some possible ways to troubleshoot and define what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I got a response from Openshift saying I should check log files to see why the PHP isn't workign. Any idea the best way to go about that? Also, they said I can't install phpmyadmin into a scaled application. How can I make it not-scaled?

Comment: If you need to make a scalable app a not scalable one, you should delete the app and recreate it from scratch as non--scalable. There is no other way, I'm afraid.